# C++ Compiling Linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, directx

I am currently getting into some DirectX Programming and just installed the DX-SDK. However, when I open the most basic sample File (Tutorial01, just displays a blue background) in Visual Studio (2012, but that seems to be irrelevant) and compile it I get a working output.

When I start an empty c++ project, make a new file called main.cpp and copy and paste the code from the tutorial, do the same with the resource.h file and also go to Project settings->Configuration Properties->Linker and copy the "Input" from the sample to my own project and then compile my project I get the following error output:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory
```

The Header is included via `#include`in both, the sample and my project. However my project won't compile.

Comment: Take a look here: http://rastertek.com/dx11tut01.html maybe it helps you

Comment: thank you, the initial problem is solved, but now I get another error:

Comment: thank you, the initial problem is solved, but now I get another error:
`error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external` in main.cpp, (1,1) which is `#include <windows.h>`             and 


`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48" in function ""long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ)"`in main.obj

Comment: That should be a new question.  But you are probably not including the library to the linker.

Comment: Then I'll put a new question...I have errors over errors since the beginning with this linking stuff, unfortunately the sample is copyrighted, otherwise I would post both projects so that someone with more experience could help better...

Comment: I couldn't ask another question because of the time limit, so I did further research and could figure it out myself: I started a new Project as described in @Jack's link and totally forgot to set the links in Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new project is missing VC++ Directories settings to find the DirectX SDK include/lib paths. Starting with VS 2010, you have to explicitly set up the include/lib paths to get the DirectX SDK integrated with Visual Studio.

Since you are trying to use VS 2012 with the legacy DirectX SDK, you should be aware that the VC++ Directories settings for VS 2010 are *backwards* from what you should be using with VS 2012/VS2013. This is because the Windows 8.x SDK includes **newer** versions of most of the DirectX headers in the now outdated and deprecated legacy DirectX SDK.

The further complication is that D3DX is not present in the Windows 8.x SDK and is itself deprecated. You can make it work per the instructions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx), but keep in mind there are now [alternatives to using D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx) for Direct3D 11 you should consider.